# Uploading Image into R Markdown

Tags: r, markdown

I have an image stored on my hard drive and I want to import it into an R-Markdown document I have.

I have 2 copies in both PNG and JPEG format, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how the read functions work in the "png" and "jpg" packages.

Can someone please help?

Comment: If you're knitting to HTML, one option is something like `htmltools::tags$img(src = knitr::image_uri('image.png'))`

Comment: What is image.png?? What do I put in place of this to have my image displayed?

Comment: That's the filepath to the image.

Comment: Give me an example because I have tried this before with every permutation of the file path I have and it has not worked.

Comment: Here is my path for the file: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\UMM\Classes\SPATIAL STATS\HW1\Hennepin County.png what do I do next?

Comment: ...put it in in as a string in place of `'image.png'`, chuck the whole thing in a code chunk in your file, and knit. If it's erroring out, read the error.

Comment: Thanks for trying - here is the error I receive:                                               Error in if (fileSize <= 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: That means your path doesn't lead to a file.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the

```
![name](path)
```

format, here name does not matter, is just a name that you want to give to a figure, as an example you can use an internet image such as:

```
![Phyllogeny of bats](http://currents.plos.org/treeoflife/files/2011/02/figure1final.jpg)
```

that will translate in your knitted documento to

[image: Phyllogeny of bats]

for an image in the same folder as your working directory you can just put the name of the image:

```
![myyu](MYYU.png)
```

if not you have to add the path to the folder that depends on your OS on how to specify it, I recommend you to just put your image in the folder of your working directory. And just one last thing, I usually have less problems with PNG files than JPG for some reason

If you need more help with that just let me know

Comment: Where should this image be located on my hard drive? I have tried this code in 20 different ways and its still not working.

Comment: I worked it out myself!